# how to edit a textfield values in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Here i add my sample code.i have a static values getting from state now i want to change this values

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.selectedVal);
    var name,
        gender,
        city = "";

    this.props.data.map((row, index) => {
        // console.log(index);
        if (this.props.selectedVal === index) {
            gender = row[0];
            name = row[1];
            city = row[2];
        }
        return [];
    });

    return (
        <Dialog
            open={this.props.open}
            onClose={this.handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
            aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        >
            <h1>Edit User</h1>
            <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description" />
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{ name: "", gender: "", city: "" }}
                    onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}
                >
                    {props => (
                        <form>
                            <TextField margin="dense" id="name" label="Name" value={name} />
                            <br />
                            <TextField
                                margin="dense"
                                id="gender"
                                label="Gender"
                                value={gender}
                            />
                            <br />
                            <TextField margin="dense" label="City" value={city} />
                        </form>
                    )}
                </Formik>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
                    RESET
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
                    SUBMIT
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
    );
}
```

I am getting the values from the table row.Now i want to change these values using formik. How can I edit these values

Answer (score 2):

Add a onChange listener in your textfield and map the value to a state variable:

```
textChange(e) {
  const value = e.target.value
  this.setState({ value })
}

render() {
  return (
    <TextField value={this.state.value} onChange={this.textChange} .. />
  )
}
```

If you want to handle more values from different textfields using one method try something like this:

```
textChange(e) {
  const id = e.target.id
  const value = e.target.value
  this.setState({ [id]: value })
}

render() {
  return (
    <TextField id="gender" value={this.state.gender} onChange={this.textChange} .. />
    <TextField id="dense" value={this.state.dense} onChange={this.textChange} .. />
  )
}
```

Comment: i am adding onChange Listener but values are not changed.  here i add my sample codeSandbox link [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/64kw5vw0jz)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you get data with props from parent component. And, if I get it wright, question is how to change state of parent component? You need to add to props function binded to parent`s context and use setState there.